# Moderator post notices are being auto-removed by bounties

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, post-notices

So, on [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/44010/revisions), I added the *Honeypot question* post notice, and if you can see what's been deleted on that post, you'll understand why.

Subsequently, a bounty was started and a bounty post notice was also attached to the question. When the bounty ended, the bounty post notice was auto-removed by the Community user, as it should be.

However, somewhere between the time I added the post notice and today, the *Honeypot question* post notice was removed, and not by a moderator (or that would appear in the revision history). I suspect that either the bounty post notice replaced the original notice, or upon removal, Community removed both simultaneously.

Ideally, moderator post notices should be removed by moderators (or have a set timer like locks). They shouldn't be accidentally removed by users starting a bounty on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notice wasn't actually removed; there was a bug in the logic when denormalizing the "does this post have notices?" information. This caused no notice to be displayed, even though there actually was one. Fixed now; thanks!