# "Remove post notice" option available on a question without a moderator-only notice

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools, post-notices

Take, for example, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118375/is-there-a-good-cognitive-architecture-for-implementing-intelligent-software-age). It was migrated from SO to Programmers and the asker put a bounty on it.

Now I see the "remove post notice" option in the mod tools, but there is no [moderator-only notice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/). I haven't tried it (even for science) to see if it'd remove, the migration banner, the bounty banner, or nothing at all, but it seems that the option should not be enabled in the first place.

This may be related to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109586/moderator-post-notices-are-being-auto-removed-by-bounties) from a couple weeks ago.

---

See [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111611/remove-post-notice-option-available-on-a-question-without-a-moderator-only-not/111613#111613) and comments on it for more details. Looks like it's possible to add a bounty notice to a post that already has a mod notice and both notices are shown as expected. But using the "remove post notice" option on a post like that removes both the mod notice and the bounty notice. I think "remove post notice" should only affect the moderator notice.

Answer (score 3):

So yeah: now, when you start a bounty, you get the option of both picking a pre-defined *reason* **and** entering a custom message. *That's the notice.* So if you remove it, there's still a bounty... But both the predefined reason *and* the custom text go away.

The migration does not appear to have any connection to this. Not that that stopped me from removing both the bounty, the migration, and the question itself while testing this. Just to be sure, y'know. *For **Science***.

FWIW, the question is back, here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118904/is-there-a-good-cognitive-architecture-for-implementing-intelligent-software-age

Comment: Ahha. Interesting. It sounds to me like if someone puts a bounty on their question, moderators are no longer able to add a potentially important notice to it. Perhaps tracking the two kinds of notices separately would be a good idea. Would a bounty notice ever need to be removed without refunding the bounty?

Comment: I suppose it's possible. Though now I'm sorta interested in finding out what happens when you add a bounty to a question that already *has* a notice...

Comment: I just tried it. The two notices coexist in peace and harmony - both  are shown. Using the "remove notice" option removes both notices. Looks like an inconsistency to me. :)

Comment: Props to waffles for building that right then! But, that's really just more justification for letting you add / remove a notice without messing with the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this feature is working as intended.

Comment: mmm? really? The bounty notice was removed of this post.. :(

Comment: What do you mean?  I added the bounty and then removed the notice, and it appears as I would expect.